# prestashop atal error: Uncaught Unknown column 'h.live_edit' in 'field list'

Tags: prestashop, upgrade

I upgraded a website from the 1.6.1 to the 1.7.4 version and the control panel seems to be ok. But then I noticed a big errors.

In the fronted I get a blank page and this error:"
Fatal error: Uncaught Unknown column 'h.live_edit' in 'field list'

```
SELECT h.name as hook, m.id_module, h.id_hook, m.name as module, h.live_edit FROM ps_module m INNER JOIN ps_module_shop module_shop ON (module_shop.id_module = m.id_module AND module_shop.id_shop = 1 AND module_shop.enable_device & 1) INNER JOIN ps_module_shop ms ON ms.id_module = m.id_module INNER JOIN ps_hook_module hm ON hm.id_module = m.id_module INNER JOIN ps_hook h ON hm.id_hook = h.id_hook LEFT JOIN ps_module_group mg ON mg.id_module = m.id_module WHERE (h.name != "displayPayment") AND (hm.id_shop = 1) AND (mg.id_shop = 1 AND mg.id_group IN (1)) GROUP BY hm.id_hook, hm.id_module ORDER BY hm.position
```

thrown in /web/htdocs/www.hairimport.it/home/shop/classes/db/Db.php on line 746"

What can it be?

Thanks to all of you will answer!

Answer (score 0):

You must have had a migration error of either a native piece of code or an incompatible module because on 1.7, the Hook table does not have a live_edit field.

Could you give the complete list of errors, that we can see the trigger, to find the cause

Regards,